# what is __gmon start_?

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc

I'm trying to reverse engineering a loading file, with winhex I found the binary strings by looking on the loading file by using WinHex:

[image]

Are those some commands for bash Linux?
it is loading .so libraries then some functions, is it possible to understand the loading sequence? why the gmon_start is first? why is it loading a few libraries first then call function and only then load another libries?

Comment: What do you get if you do `file the-file-name`?

Comment: Don't post text as a picture. It is harder to read. And violates accessibility guidelines, as for example it makes it very very hard for blind people to read.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor sorry about the image as text, what do you mean by file the file name/

Comment: There is a command `file` run `file whatever-the-name-of-the-file-that-you-are-discussing-is-called`.

Comment: You can amend the question, by clicking edit. No need to apologise.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor ah i understand, i have all these libs that in the picture, decompiled the loading file with binwalk. But i don't understand the sequence of functions start like FTM_GETINFO etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have some sort of executable file. There is a package on Debian (and probably other Distros) call bin-utils. It has tools for interpreting the content of this type of file. The default version on your system, will probably only work with files for the same architecture of your OS/hardware. But you can get versions for many other architectures, and maybe a version that does them all.

Comment: it is loading file for embennded linux

Comment: the question is is it any info on how it loads in bash? I mean is it possible to understand from which library for example "_return address" from what library and what goes after what

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clearer. I don't understand this comment, except that it is an attempt to explain the question, and something about libraries.

Comment: @JeezyWonder Currently, the question does not ask how it "loads in bash". Do consider updating your question to make it more specific.

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry this is my best attempt at guessing what the question is. I have put in requests for clarification. I so nothing more that I can do. Care to give it a try?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor My comment was aimed primarily at the OP. The question is too broad as it is and they ask follow-up questions (or reformulations, it's not clear) in comments. I'm just trying to get the question into an answerable shape; I'm most certainly not the person to answer it.